# Display many MRI slices in one window

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

Is it possible to display all MRI images side by side in one VTK , or maybe even QT window? 
So far I've got all MRI slices from reconstruction in a matrix vector and I can scroll them (write in c++). I don't know if I can put all these images in one window and display them. Below I enclose example image with what i want to achieve. Thanks for any response.

[image: MRI Slices]

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want, you can divide it as a series of sequential steps:

- First, you need to scan and read MRI dicom files, which can be done through `vtkDICOMDirectory` and `vtkDICOMReader`.
- Assuming you have an MRI volume, you can extract each slice through `vtkExtractVOI`, and map this information to a `vtkImageActor`, which you can add to a renderer. In turn, you need to set the **viewport** on the renderer, so that you can display images side by side, as you want.

Here is a small example, please adapt it to your needs:

```
//Use vtkDICOMDirectory to scan a directory with MRI images
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMDirectory> dicomDir = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMDirectory>::New();
dicomDir->SetDirectoryName("**Insert the path to your images here**");
dicomDir->RequirePixelDataOn();
dicomDir->Update();

int n = dicomDir->GetNumberOfSeries();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMReader>::New();

if (n > 0){
    //Read the first series found (just for example)
    reader->SetFileNames(dicomDir->GetFileNamesForSeries(0));
    reader->Update();

    //Get the extent
    vtkImageData* mriVolume = reader->GetOutput();
    mriVolume->GetExtent(mriExtent);
    xmin = mriExtent[0];
    xmax = mriExtent[1];
    ymin = mriExtent[2];
    ymax = mriExtent[3];
    zmin = mriExtent[4];
    zmax = mriExtent[5];

    //Extract a slice of interest
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractVOI> extractSlice = vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractVOI>::New();
    extractSlice->SetInputData(mriVolume);

    // Define viewport ranges (Adapt here to it covers your entire range of slices. Here we only create 4 viewports, so 4 images in total)
    double xmins[4] = {0,.5,0,.5};
    double xmaxs[4] = {0.5,1,0.5,1};
    double ymins[4] = {0,0,.5,.5};
    double ymaxs[4]= {0.5,0.5,1,1};

    vtkImageData* slice;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        extractSlice->SetVOI(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,i,i);
        extractSlice->Update();

        //Get the image data
        slice = extractSlice->GetOutput();

        //Image Actor
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> imageActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
        imageActor->GetMapper()->SetInputData(slice);

        //Add a renderer
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
        renderer->SetViewport(xmins[i],ymins[i],xmaxs[i],ymaxs[i]);
        renderer->AddActor(imageActor);
        renderer->ResetCamera();

        //QT+VTK connection (assumes you have a QVTKWidget named mriWidget)
        ui->mriWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);
        ui->mriWidget->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
    }
} else {
    std::cerr << "No DICOM images in directory!" << std::endl;
}
```

**References**:

- https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleViewports
- https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/Transparency
- https://dgobbi.github.io/vtk-dicom/doc/api/directory.html